# Excel VBA Invalid procedure call or argument when makeing formula

Tags: excel, vba

Code:

```
Cells(Z, 2).Formula = "AVERAGE(" & Left(SumCP, Len(SumCP) - 2) & ")"
Cells(Z, 3).Formula = "AVERAGE(" & Left(SumFl, Len(SumFl) - 2) & ")"
Cells(Z, 4).Formula = "AVERAGE(" & Left(SumICP, Len(SumICP) - 2) & ")"
Cells(Z, 5).Formula = "AVERAGE(" & Left(SumIFL, Len(SumIFL) - 2) & ")"`
```

This code will give the text I want but still giva a Error 5 Invalid procedure call or argument when makeing formula.

If I change it so it will be a formula like this:

```
Cells(Z, 2).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Left(SumCP, Len(SumCP) - 2) & ")"
Cells(Z, 3).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Left(SumFl, Len(SumFl) - 2) & ")"
Cells(Z, 4).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Left(SumICP, Len(SumICP) - 2) & ")"
Cells(Z, 5).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Left(SumIFL, Len(SumIFL) - 2) & ")"
```

"Run Time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined-error" occurs.
Why is that and how do I fix it? Thanks for all help

Comment: What's the value of `SumCP`? and is the error thrown on the first line?

Comment: It would help if you provided what the formula looks like. Regardless of whether it is what you think you want, there is something wrong with it.

Comment: The resulting formula looks like this
AVERAGE(B6; B7; B8; B9)

Comment: Ant the error is on the first line, yes

Comment: The formula works if I add the = after the macro is done

Comment: You need to separate your values with comma's not semi-colons. `=Average(B6, B7, B8, B9)` should work.

Comment: I would use `Split` and 'Join' to manage the list of cells here. This code will fail if the length of the cell address is more than 2 characters (i.e. `B10`).

Comment: I'd agree with @JosephC - but can't test it.  As formula is being added through VBA it has to be in US format with the comma (or use `FormulaLocal`) - I've not had any experience with other localities, but think that's how it works.

Comment: The macro works now but it still throws error 5 after executing the macro. I will look at the join command and see if I can make it work and stop the error. Thanks everybody!